# How many uses does a scroll scribed by a player character have?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting

How many uses does a scroll created by a player character have?

During random scroll generation, DM is called to roll a die that represents the uses the scroll has. Is it the same case for a player that scribes a scroll, or does the new scroll only have one use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### One use, but you can scribe more uses if you pay the cost for each use.

The D&D 3.5 FAQ covers this eventuality:

> **According to the rules, creating a magic item takes one day per 1,000 gp in its base cost, with a minimum of one day. The random scroll generation charts in the *DMG* state that a scroll could have up to six spells on it. Does this mean that when I create a scroll I can place six spells on it? Does it count as one scroll or six for purposes of item creation (in other words, should it take one day or six)?**
>
> A scroll with multiple spells counts as a single item for the purpose of determining the time to create it. A divine scroll with six castings of *cure light wounds* (market price 150 gp) would take 1 day to scribe; a divine scroll with six castings of *heal* (market price 9,900 gp) would take 10 days to scribe. You’d need to expend (and prepare, if that’s required by your class) the spell once for each time it appears on the scroll. The act of scribing *cure light wounds* the first time onto a scroll expends *cure light wounds*, which means you’d need to have another one prepared to scribe it again.